# postgres GENERATED ALWAYS jsonb with refers to other columns inside a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, generated-columns

Trying to generate a jsonb column that will look like this:
`["c:cluster-x", "ns:cluster-x/namespace-1"]`

The cluster and namespace will be taken from other fields. I'm struggling with finding a way to concat it successfully

Also an array literal will be fine here, like this `'{c:cluster-x, ns:cluster-x/namespace-1}'`

I tried something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN resources jsonb GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('["c:"' || my_table."clusterName" || ']'::jsonb) STORED;
```

but getting:
`Detail: Expected JSON value, but found "]".`

postgres version 13.4

Comment: The resulting string `["c:"something]` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if `my_table."clusterName"` is a string, shouldn't it be `["c:something"]`, an array with a single element? jsonb supports arrays

Comment: That is not what your code generates.

Comment: right thanks @LaurenzAlbe! that was a big part of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting a single character `]` as jsonb. That's why you're getting this error. Also, the `:` is missing (misplaced?) between key and value.

This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN resources jsonb 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (('[{"c":"' || "clusterName" || '"}]')::jsonb) STORED;
```

**Note**: This solution will return NULL if the column `clusterName` is NULL.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d9534c08f174014a564d67cb498f286e)

Comment: Great, it works, thanks :)
changed it so it will generate an array of strings like this:
`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN resources jsonb GENERATED ALWAYS AS (('["c:' || "clusterName" || '","ns:' || "clusterName" || '/' || "namespace" || '"]')::jsonb) STORED;`